# How to I get rid of bottom white space in a div after positioning h4 and a tag absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting a little white space in the div row 3 and 4 after positioning absolute of the h4 and a tags. Maybe around 5px to the bottom of each of the row divs. I tried a negative margin on the divs but that didn't seem to work.I also tried offseting the bottom position eg -4em but that didnt work either.

The red space as shown in this screenshot:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxHtDrLLi2x5WFpJaFd0eTRhYkE/view?usp=sharing

```
   <div class="MainContent">
  <main>

    <section class="recentProjects">



    <div class="row1">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/422.4x400/000000/fff" />
      <h4>Webcosoftwares</h4>
      <a href="#">Visit website</a>
   </div>

   <div class="row2">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/422.4x400/000000/fff" />
     <h4>Webcosoftwares</h4>
     <a  href="#">Visit website</a>
  </div>


    </section>
    <section class="recentProjects2">



    <div class="row3">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/422.4x400/000000/fff" />
      <h4>Webcosoftwares</h4>
      <a href="#">Visit website</a>
   </div>

   <div class="row4">
     <img src="https://dummyimage.com/422.4x400/000000/fff" />
     <h4>Webcosoftwares</h4>
     <a  href="#">Visit website</a>
  </div>


    </section>


  </main>

</div>

main > .recentProjects2{
  width:90%; /*960px*/
  height:100%;
  padding-left:5%;
  padding-right:5%;

  float:left;
}


main .recentProjects2 > .row3{
 width:44%; /*50% === 480pxx  40% === 384*/



  float:left;
}
main .recentProjects2  .row3 > img{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;

}
main .recentProjects2  .row4 > img{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;


}
main .recentProjects2 > .row4{
 width:44%; /*50% === 480pxx  44% === 422.4px*/


  float:right;
}

main .recentProjects2 > .row3{
  margin-right:3%; /*48 pixels*/

}
main .recentProjects2 > .row4{
    margin-left:3%; /*48 pixels*/

}

.recentProjects2{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;


}
.row3 {
 position:relative;
 background-color:red;
 height:100%;

}


.row4{
 position:relative;
 background-color:red;
}
.recentProjects2 .row3 > h4{
  width:100%;
  font-size:2em;
  position:absolute;
  color:#fff;
  bottom:4em;

  text-align: center;

}
.recentProjects2 .row4 > h4{

  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  font-size:2em;

  color:#fff;
  bottom:4em;

  text-align:center;

}
.recentProjects2 .row3 > a,.recentProjects2 .row4 > a, .recentProjects .row1 > a, .recentProjects .row2 > a{
bottom:3em;

position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center;
width:25%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
line-height:100%:

}

.row3   a, .row4 a, .row1 a, .row2 a {

 background: #ae1f23;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ae1f23, #ae1f23);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ae1f23, #ae1f23);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ae1f23, #ae1f23);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ae1f23, #ae1f23);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ae1f23, #ae1f23);
 -webkit-border-radius: 4;
 -moz-border-radius: 4;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #666666;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding: .3em .7em .3em .7em;
 border: solid #ffffff 1px;
 text-decoration: none;
}



.row3   a:hover, .row4 a:hover, .row1 a:hover, .row2 a:hover {

 background-color:#d9262c;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d9262c, #d9262c);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d9262c, #d9262c);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d9262c, #d9262c);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d9262c, #d9262c);
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d9262c,#d9262c);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: Don't use background-color:red; in .row3{...} and .row4 {...}

Comment: lol it will still have white space on top the footer that i need to get rid of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.row3 img, .row4 img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

There is some whitespace below images since they are aligned at the baseline, and there is some space below it for descenders (of letters) and similar. Aligning them to the bottom (instead of the default baseline-alignment) avoids this.

Comment: Thanks alot Johannes this worked you're the real mvp :)

Comment: Most Valuable Player!

Answer (score 0):

```
.row3, .row4 {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

since you have an image in the div it comes with some spacing because of `font-size`. So nix the font size and the spacing goes away just remember to set the `font-size` again for other elements inside those divs.

Comment: Hey darham i tried this but it took my h4 and achor tag and put them out of site. I did what you said as well (adding the fontsize to the h4 and a. I used vertical align bottom as suggested by Johannes and it worked. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can always turn to jQuery or JS to resize the div to the height of the image. Johanes' answer seems to help but the red background still comes up at the top though very slightly as I resize the window. I'd use simple `jQuery` code to fix this issue to fire on document loaded(ready) and on window resize events

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".row3").css("height", $(".row3 img").height()+"px");
    $(".row4").css("height", $(".row4 img").height()+"px");
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        $(".row3").css("height", $(".row3 img").height()+"px");
        $(".row4").css("height", $(".row4 img").height()+"px");
    });
 })
```

P.S. in `$(".row3 img").height()+"px"` the `+"px"` is not really necessary i don't know why I keep using it :)